# making proprietary ELF binaries portable on Linux

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, portability, elf, portable-applications

I am searching for a way to make existing proprietary ELF-binaries, which are linked against specific versions of system libraries, portable. With portable I mean making the executable work on every system with the same processor architecture and a compatible system kernel, without necessarily having the source code of the libraries (if there is no way without having the source code, it'll be fine too).

So far I thought of two possibilities, but I don't know if they are at all possible and if yes, which to choose:

1. Searching all linked libraries and their dependencies and include them in a subdirectory of the binary and changing the Library-Path to that directory.
2. Relinking the libraries statically into the binary file to one big executable (if the program doesn't verify itself based on a checksum).

Licensing is no issue as I don't want to distribute the created portable programs, it's for private use only.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157636 | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250831 | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386027

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Searching all linked libraries and their dependencies and include them in a subdirectory of the binary and changing the Library-Path to that directory.

This would work for most shared libraries, but will not work for `libc.so.6` (which is the one most likely to give problems if your target system doesn't have new enough version).

The reason: glibc consists of over 200 separate shared libraries, which have un-versioned binary interfaces between them, and do not have a stable ABI between them. Because of this, *all* parts of glibc must come from the same build. One of these parts is `libc.so.6`. Another is `ld-linux.so`. An absolute path to the latter is *hard coded* into every dynamic executable. The end result: if you supply your own copy of `libc.so.6`, and if that copy doesn't match `/lib/ld-linux*.so.2` present on the system, then you'll see very strange crashes which you would have very hard time to explain or debug.

> Relinking the libraries statically into the binary file to one big executable.

That can't work on any UNIX system other than AIX: they all consider `a.out` and `foo.so` to be the *final* link product, which can't be linked any further.

There exists [statifier](http://statifier.sourceforge.net/), which does create a (huge) static executable out of a dynamic one. I have no experience using it.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I'll give statifier a try later today (GMT+1) and See if it can help me in some way.

Comment: Statifier doesn't seem to work that well and the other software that could help me achieve my goal (ermine) is proprietary. But at least there is a way to achieve what I thougt of.

Comment: I tried Ermine and it to works fine (using the trial version)